# Key value Observer is not getting called when there is a change in property in cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa, key-value-observing

I had 2 Objects `Obj1` and `Obj2`. Where `Obj1` is having a property `isLocalChanges`(`BOOL`) to check for any local changes made. I need to observe the change for this `isLocalChanges` if there is any changes I am setting the value to `YES`.

I written an observer for this property `isLocalChanges` in `Obj2`:

```
@interface Obj2 : NSObject
{
   Obj1 *sampleObj;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) Obj1 * sampleObj;

@end

@implementation Obj2
@synthesize sampleObj;
- (id)init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        sampleObj =  [[Obj1 alloc] init];

        [sampleObj  addObserver:self
                forKeyPath:@"isLocalChanges"
                   options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                   context:nil];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {       
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"isLocalChanges"]) {
            NSLog(@"isLocalChanges Observer");
            if ([[change objectForKey:@"new"] boolValue]) {
                 NSLog("@\n Found Local Changes...");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Declaration and usage of isLocalChanges property that I used:

```
@interface Obj1 : NSObject
    {
       BOOL _isLocalChanges;
    }
    @property (assign) BOOL isLocalChanges;
@end
```

and in the Obj1.m

did `@synthesize isLocalChanges = _isLocalChanges;`

And Inside the below method I am setting the value for isLocalChanges property.

```
-(void) localChangesMade 
{
   self.isLocalChanges = YES;
}
```

The issue is even if `isLocalChanges` property changed in `Obj1`, The method `observeValueForKeyPath:` is not triggering. At this point I am helpless an unable to find what going wrong.

Can anyone suggest me to resolve this issue...

Answer (score 0):

The object you are allocating is going out-of-scope and will be destroyed as soon as the method returns:

```
SomeObject *Obj2 =  [[SomeObject alloc] init];
```

Make it an instance variable instead.

Comment: I did that too, still same result.

Comment: @MonishKumar So the code you posted is not accurate?

Comment: @MonishKumar My answer still stands; you have a local variable which you are allocating in the `init` method.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the identifier `Obj2` for **three** different things (a) as a class name (b) as an instance variable/property and (c) as a local variable. This is *not good*.

It is probably the third use which is your immediate problem, it is probably meant to be a use of (b). Instead of:

```
if (self = [super init])
{
    SomeObject *Obj2 =  [[SomeObject alloc] init];
```

you probably want:

```
if (self = [super init])
{
    Obj2 =  [[SomeObject alloc] init];
```

etc. The `SomeObject *Obj2` local variable's lifetime is only the body of the `if`.

However that fix has you assigning an instance of type `SomeObject` to a property of type `Obj1`, so you may have a problem there as well.

Finally you never show the declaration or use of `isLocalChanges`, so there is no indication that you're actually assigning to this property using its setter - and if you're not then there won't be any KVO notifications.

Comment: I am assigning like self.isLocalChanges =  YES; in the Obj1 class. because this is a synthesized property.

Comment: I edited the post, check it and provide me with some suggestions where I am going wrong

Comment: Have you checked that you are calling `localChangesMade` on the *same* instance of `Obj1` that is referenced by `sampleObj`? (You can use `NSLog` and the `%p` format to help here.)